# Long polling in JQuery + JAVA?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, google-chrome-devtools, long-polling

I need to **hold** my request in the **server** until new data comes.I am using the **Tomcat 6**  as my web server . So  this is my **JQuery** code,

```
function sendMessage() {

    var message = $("#message").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "sendMessage.html",
        data: "message=" + message,
        dataType: "html",

        success: function(response) {

        },
        error: function(e) {
            //alert('Error: ' + e);
        },
    });
}


function startLongPolling(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "LongPoll.html",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(response) {   
            if(response != null && response !="" && response !="null")
                $("#sucess").html(response);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            //alert('Error: ' + e);
        },

        complete: function(e) {
            startLongPolling();
        },
    });
}
```

My **java** code will be ,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "LongPoll.html", method=RequestMethod.POST )
public @ResponseBody String longLongPolling(HttpSession session) {

    String sessionId = session.getId().toString();
    AgentState agentState = ApplicaionManager.agentDetail.get(sessionId);
    String message = null;

    if(ApplicaionManager.agentDetail.containsKey(sessionId)){

        while(true){

            if(agentState.isStateChange() == true){
                message = agentState.getMessage();
                if(message != null)
                    agentState.setStateChange(false);
                System.out.println("Break for session "+sessionId+" due to Agent State changed");
                break;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("While exited for session"+sessionId);
    return message;
}
```

But there is a `continous request sent to server` for every **11 seconds** . I don't know how it is possible. I have checked this with **chrome developer tools**.

[image]

Hope our stack users will help me.

Comment: does it print "Break for session.." in console?

Comment: I any change in the state means , It prints the "Break for session.." .

Comment: please paste your complete jquery code

Comment: @ UVM . I updated my code. Please check it.

Comment: Your request is probably timing out. jQuery doesn't have a default timeout value set but your browser, OS or server may have.

Comment: Also, please try with other browsers

Comment: How to check it with other browsers ?

Comment: Can you try removing the dataType: "html" from ajax call?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal / expected. Depending on your browser and (especially) front-end server (Apache/NGINX) and web-server (Tomcat?) configuration you will have:

- maximum wait time for the first response (connection timeout, probably 10 seconds in your case)
- maximum wait time for the complete response

These setting basically prevent the server from being spammed with requests that never complete and running out of threads in the thread pool.

You could increase these values, however you should always create your code like this with timeouts in mind. Basically you want to do on the client side:

- Open long pull
- Wait for response
- If received, continue
- If (timeout) error, go to step 1

Please note that this solution is not scalable: usually you would have (for example) 200 thread processing incoming requests. The idea is that they finish fast. If the thread pool is exhausted, users will have to wait for a new connection. But with 200 threads you are able to serve well over 2.000 users. But not if threads are blocked because of long pool.

If possible, you should really look into [WebSockets](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/websockets_and_java_ee_7), which are now available in new versions of Java.

***EDIT*** As Konrad suggested below, you can use something like [socket.io](http://socket.io/), which falls-back automatically to other mechanisms. There's a Java-based implementation for sever-side available call [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere), but I haven't tried it though.

Comment: Check out http://socket.io, it is a nice JavaScript library for creating socket connections. It also offers backwards compatibility for older browsers.

Comment: socket.io is sweet, but server-side is limited to NodeJS (naturally). If you want to use it on a Java-based backend, you need JEE7-compatible application server. Quick Google search turned up this: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere for Java-backends and socket.io on frontend.